# React Unit Testing: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'navigate')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, preact

I'm doing unit testing in react for function with querySelector and select property of querySelector with logout as following. (oj-gbu-app-shell) is company internal html tag library.

```
  async nextState(): Promise<UserSessionState> {
    const shell: any = document.querySelector('oj-gbu-app-shell');
    shell.navigate([{ path: 'logout' }]);
    UserSessionFacade.setUserSessionExpired(!this.isCancelledState());
    return new UserSessionActiveState(this.getConfig());
  }
```

When I'm doing unit testing as following code.

```
  it('Should transit to Active State', async () => {
    testCase = new SessionExpiredState(testConfig, true);
    const nextState: UserSessionState = await testCase.nextState();
    expect(nextState.constructor.name).to.be.eq('UserSessionActiveState');
    expect(sessionState).to.be.false;
  });
```

It always return me error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'navigate')
```

Comment: The issue is pretty clear; `shell` is `null`, as the element evidently cannot be found. Beyond that, we cannot say, as you've not provided how you're rendering the document.